# Bootstrap form elements won't go in-line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have three form elements but I can't seem to get them to all go in-line together. If I pick two of them, they work but as soon as there's three, they go out of alignment. Note, the dropdown list is an `asp:dropdownlist` control so I took the generated html source instead and replaced the values with 1,2,3 for ease of reading.

See [JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/topz45ot/).

Code in case you can't access the JSfiddle:

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" runat="server">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
                    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddreg" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ddreg" class="form-control input-lg">
    <option value="0">&lt;Select Number&gt;</option>
    <option value="2">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>

</select>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="comments" placeholder="Enter any comments..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit">Add</button>
                    </span>
                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div>
    </form>
```

How do I make them all in-line on the same row, with 100% width?

Comment: Encapsulate your select inside a div or span tag using the `input-group-btn` class. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/topz45ot/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the grid of the bootstrap like `xs-* md-* lg-*` for the columns to be inline, I have made some changes to fiddle. Take a look at it. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/topz45ot/1/)

Comment: That kind of works - thanks. But how do I make it 100% width?

Comment: I would remove the `form-inline` class from the form, encapsulate the <select> element inside a <div> and set the width for `input-group-lg` to auto. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/topz45ot/4/.

Comment: This looks perfect on jsfiddle but doesn't work in my own code. Inspecting the elements as displayed, the dropdown list seems to be set to 1% width and if I change it in the console, it breaks everything! Any ideas?